# Cannot understand command substitution in Fish shell

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, fish

In sh:

```
~$ `echo ls`
bin/  Desktop/
```

But in fish:

```
fish: Illegal command name “(echo ls)”
~% (echo ls)
```

(Note that the error message appears above the command line.)

```
~% echo (echo ls)
ls
~% eval (echo ls)
bin/  Desktop/

fish: Illegal command name “(echo ls)”
exec (echo ls)
     ^
~% exec (echo ls)
```

It seems that command substitution only works as parameters of a command, not as a command itself? Why?

Well, the help doc does say

> If a parameter contains a set of parenthesis, the text enclosed by the parenthesis will be interpreted as a list of commands.

But still, why?

Comment: Since the error message appears above the command line and it appears that you then edited it before resubmitting it, it's confusing since none of the commands you show produce that error. Perhaps you should insert `(echo ls)` after the error message for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I miss the '()'.  Edited.

Comment: I've starting doing it like this `echo ls | bash`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Update

This answer was written ten year ago in 2010.
Recent versions of fish (I tested on 3.1.2) updated and `set cmd ls; $cmd` is valid now.

## How

This because command substitutions belong to parameter expansions and are not allowed as commands.

A similar example:

in sh:

```
tmpls=ls
$tmpls
```

But in fish:

```
% set cmd ls; $cmd
fish: Variables may not be used as commands.
...
```

## Why

In short, it's good for verifiability

This [article](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2005/12/linux-20051218.ars/3) explains details:

> Since it is allowed to use variables as commands in regular shells, it is impossible to reliably check the syntax of a script. For example, this snippet of bash/zsh code may or may not be legal, depending on your luck. Do you feel lucky?
>
> ```
>     if true; then if [ $RANDOM -lt 1024 ]; then END=fi; else END=true; fi; $END
> ```
>
> Both bash and zsh try to determine if the command in the current buffer is finished when the user presses the return key, but because of issues like this, they will sometimes fail. Even worse, this piece of perfectly legal code is rejected by bash:
>
> ```
>   FI=fi; foo() { if true; then true; $FI; }
> ```
>
> Fish avoids this kind of problem, since variables are not allowed as commands. Anything you can do with variables as commands can be done in a much cleaner way using either the eval command or by using functions.

For the same reason, command substitutions are not allowed as commands.

(Note: The cited example is not fair, since 'if' and 'fi' are not simple commands but reserved words.  See comments below.)

Comment: For a discussion of this issue regarding Bash, see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: the article you cite in your "why" section is plain wrong (at least as far as this section is concerned). A command like `FI=fi; foo() { if true; then true; $FI; }` is *not* valid shell syntax, so it is correctly flagged as a syntax error by all POSIX shells. Words like `fi` are reserved words, and they are recognized before word expansion which expands `$FI` to `fi`.

Comment: tldr; "Anything you can do with variables as commands can be done in a much cleaner way using either the eval command..."

Comment: The example that you gave is perfectly valid fish code.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick It was invalid ten years ago. Thanks for reminding me to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the order of expansions.

From `help expand-command-substitution` in `fish`:

> When combining multiple parameter expansions, expansions are performed
>      in the following order:

```
 * Command substitutions
 * Variable expansions
 * Bracket expansion
 * Pid expansion
 * Wildcard expansion
```

> Expansions are performed from right to left, nested bracket expansions
>      are performed from the inside and out.

From `man bash`:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde  expansion,  parameter,  variable  and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done
>          in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

Comment: I'm still confusing.  It seems that fish doesn't try to expand the Command substitution, and takes (echo ls) literally as a command.