# Execute command stored in variable in fish shell

Tags: fish

I would like to run the following command:

```
for i in git python gcc java pip
    $i --version                
end
```

But fish tells me to use a function. I am not sure what the best way to do this is.

Comment: There's a nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3282733/7552

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `eval` command works for this, but would a function be more appropriate as fish suggests?

```
for i in git python gcc java pip
    eval $i --version                
end
```

Comment: AFAIK using `eval` is the only way to do what you want in Fish. I don't know how `eval` works behind the scenes, but I have experienced slower than usual performance when using `eval`. I try to avoid it nowadays except when testing boolean `true` or `false` values.

Comment: @JorgeBucaran have you opened an issue regarding this?